# can't get DB Connection using JNDI datasource on JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, jndi, jboss5.x

I'm studying how to build java webapps for JBossAS 5.1.0 and I'm trying to build a very basic jsp web app on JBossAS5 using a JNDI datasource for data access.

When trying to open a connection I get this exception:

```
21:42:52,834 ERROR [STDERR] Cannot get connection: org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException:
Unable to get managed connection for hedgehogDB; - nested throwable:
(javax.resource.ResourceException: Unable to get managed connection for hedgehogDB)
```

The datasource is deployed ok, I can see it in the jmx-console & the database files are getting created ok.

Java code in question where the exception is thrown:

```
static public Connection getHedgehogConnection()
{
    Connection result = null;
    try 
    {
        String DS_Context = "java:comp/env/jdbc/hedgehogDB";

        Context initialContext = new InitialContext();

        if ( initialContext == null)
            log("JNDI problem. Cannot get InitialContext.");

        DataSource datasource = (DataSource)initialContext.lookup(DS_Context);

        if (datasource != null)
            result = datasource.getConnection();
        else
            log("Failed: datasource was null");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        log("Cannot get connection: " + ex);
    }

    return result;
}
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app>
    <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/hedgehogDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

jboss-web.xml:

```
<jboss-web>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/hedgehogDB</res-ref-name>
        <jndi-name>java:/hedgehogDB</jndi-name>
    </resource-ref>
</jboss-web>
```

hedgehogdb-ds.xml

```
<datasources>
   <local-tx-datasource>
      <jndi-name>hedgehogDB</jndi-name>
      <connection-url>jdbc:hsqldb:${jboss.server.data.dir}${/}hypersonic${/}hedgehogDB</connection-url>
      <driver-class>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</driver-class>
      <user-name>sa</user-name>
      <password></password>
      <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
      <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
      <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
      <track-statements/>
      <security-domain>HsqlDbRealm</security-domain>
      <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
      <metadata>
         <type-mapping>Hypersonic SQL</type-mapping>
      </metadata>
      <depends>jboss:service=Hypersonic,database=hedgehogDB</depends>
   </local-tx-datasource>

   <mbean code="org.jboss.jdbc.HypersonicDatabase"
     name="jboss:service=Hypersonic,database=hedgehogDB">
     <attribute name="Database">hedgehogDB</attribute>
     <attribute name="InProcessMode">true</attribute>
   </mbean>

</datasources>
```

This is my first time in this environment and I suspect that I'm missing something really basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

The culprit was this in hedgehogdb-ds.xml :

```
<security-domain>HsqlDbRealm</security-domain>
```

HsqlDbRealm was configured for a different DS & was causing the connection to fail.

Answer (score 1):

it's also possible to in -ds.xml use < application-managed-security / > instead of < security-domain >, at lease in Jboss6

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it appears that you get the DataSource correctly -- otherwise it would be null. So the problem happens when you try to get the connection.

Looking at the [HSQLDB docs](http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlDocsFrame.html), it seems that your URL needs a "file" component:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:${jboss.server.data.dir}${/}hypersonic${/}hedgehogDB
```

And, as a general coding comment, (1) use a standard logging package, rather than a homegrown "log" method, and (2) when logging an exception, use the logger call (supported by both Log4J and Commons Logging, probably others) that takes an exception as a paramter (so that you get the full stack trace).

Comment: file - odd, none of the examples I've seen use that, it might be required for the jdbc DriverManager style of connection, changing it caused more exceptions